# rhc add alias - for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Openshift has this `rhc add alias` command which is very neat.

I can alias as many domain to a specific Openshift application. Without any cumbersome stuff,just do:

```
rhc add alias myapp www.somewhere.com
```

and its ok.

Is there a facility in GAE cloud similar to this? That is, without applying the domain for Google Apps for Business and those sort of hoops.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add different custom domains in your Developers' Console, App Engine Section under Settings and Custom domain tab. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but google wants to 'validate' domain, and register it using Google App for Business which is just cumbersome and cannot be automated with code

Comment: I think that's the case only when you want to use advanced things such as SSL certificates or secondary domains. Could you upload a screenshot of that message? Obviously verification is a very important step, but that may be done in App Engine.